# Traction, sidesliding

Tags: tire

Has anyone experienced poor traction and side sliding using these Kevlar type tyres. My front wheel has slid sideways and caused me to come of the bike on three occasions now since I had them fitted. Would be grateful for your response. Thanks Tim

Comment: Which specific tyres? All the tyres I've bought in the last few years have kevlar belts, and they handle differently to each other. Kevlar beads shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As you've written it, your post is just a survey, rather than an answerable question. Really, the only possible answers are multiples of "Yeah, I've had that too" and "Never had that problem." So, suppose you get some number of yays and some number of nays -- then what? Are you asking for advice about what to do about the problem? Something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as currently written, it's a survey, not an answerable question.

Comment: What brand and model of tyre are you using ?  What air pressure are they at front and back?  How wide is the rim?  What surfaces are you sliding on - dirt or gravel or tarmac or concrete, wet or dry ?   What's the tread pattern on these tyres?   What do the three slides have in common - were they sharp or were you leaning or damp?

Comment: Is the kevlar in a belt as a puncture protection layer, or is it in the bead so that the tyre is "folding" ?

Comment: After two days with no clarification I've cast my vote. I'll happily retract it or vote to reopen if the question is made answerable

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing it's not the Kevlar belt that's causing the issue so much as the correlation between a Kevlar belt and an overall stiff tire. One of the most important qualities of a tire is its suppleness: how easily it deforms and contours itself to the uneven surface of the road. By deforming easily, you maximize surface area and increase grip. By adding lots of layers of puncture protection, some tires become rigid and don't handle sideways load all that well.

I don't necessarily recommend different tires: only you can determine whether the added puncture protection is worth taking more gradual turns. Push down hard on the outside pedal while cornering, and avoid taking turns over manhole covers, raised paint, train tracks, or any other type of road adornment, because they all can be pretty slick.

Comment: Within kevlar tyres stiffness varies because of compound and construction. When I switched to marathon plus from another kevlar tyre (I'd worn out the back) I noticed a reduction in grip. The marathon plus has a stiff sidewall and a compound designed to wear slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are slipping due to an abrupt change in road conditions (hitting a frozen puddle, gully, tram rail, etc.) when you are slipping with your front wheel, that's a) a sure sign that your front tire is a bad brand, and b) a significant security problem.

On a): Usually, you have a much higher load on your rear wheel, so that is the first to slip. If you slip with the front wheel first, it indicates that it has significantly lower grip than the rear wheel. The grip is determined by the rubber mixture that is in contact with the road, and that depends entirely on the brand.

On b): Slipping with the front wheel means you instantly fall with no hope of recovery. This is worse than with the rear wheel, where you may still be able to catch yourself when it starts slipping due to ground conditions. In either case, slipping is something that is to be avoided at all costs, so you want the best grip tires you can get.

Kevlar or not, get yourself a tire you can trust. My experience tells me, that there are huge differences in tire grip, find a brand with good grip.

Comment: But the front wheel is the first to encounter a slippery patch of road. Assuming constant grip is an assumption too far.

Comment: @ChrisH True. I didn't think about road conditions being the cause because in that case it would not cross my mind to ask about the grip of the tire. I have included a mention of the road conditions in the first sentence now.